# Inertia Tensor of an Ellipsoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, integration, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I tried calculating the Inertia Tensor for a symmetric ellipsoid given by the equation;

$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$

I had no trouble finding the diagonal elements for the tensor, i.e. the Moments of Inertia about the x, y and z axes.

However, the non diagonal elements, i.e. the products of inertia come out to be non zero values. As per symmetry, the products of inertia should be zero. But the integration provides a non zero value.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so could someone try proving how the integration i.e. the products of inertia for this ellipsoid would be zero.

I used spherical coordinates to find the volume integral.

Edit: Here is my work for better understanding;

**Step 1: Transformation to spherical coordinate system**

$x = arsin\phi cos\theta$

$y = brsin\phi sin\theta$

$z = crcos\phi$

$\phi$ is the polar angle, $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle and $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

$0 \lt \phi, \theta \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$

$0 \lt r \lt 1$

(This is for the first quadrant only, the obtained answer can be multiplied 8 times corresponding to the whole space)

**Step 2: The elements of the Tensor**

$ I_{xy}=-\int_V\rho xy dV$

(I'm skipping the moments of inertia about the x, y, z axes here in this edit since I had no trouble calculating those)

$I_{xy} = -\iiint_V\rho xy dxdydz$

$dxdydz = r^2  abc  sin\phi  d\phi  d\theta  dr$

**Step 3: Integration for $I_{xy}$**
The integration is provided in the image provided herewith;
[It would take a while to type out the entire working so, I've attached this image instead and as you can see the Integral is non zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNHHV.jpg)

Comment: Can you please show what you have done so someone can explain where you are making an error? Stating that the answer is wrong or that you are not sure what you are doing wrong is too vague and help based on this information is impossible. Thanks.

Comment: @josephh yes sure, it's in the new edit

Comment: Thanks. I’m glad you got an answer to your question. Just FYI. Providing links to written work is also not recommended. If you ever need help again, if you could include your full question using LaTex that would be great. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The off-diagonal elements should indeed be zero. I believe your mistake is in the limits of integration you use for the spherical coordinate angles. The azimuthal angle ($\theta$ in your notation) ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ while the polar angle ($\phi$ in your notation) ranges from $0$ to $\pi$. With the appropriate limits, the integral of $\sin 2\theta$ with respect to $\theta$ vanishes.

Note: in physics and engineering, $\theta$ and $\phi$ usually denote the polar and azimuthal angles, respectively.